# How do you access a class's property inside a list...inside another class?

Tags: python, list

I think I trapped myself in a Russian Doll.

I tried to make a smaller-scale Pokemon "engine", and decided to work on implementing moves. The one thing is, I got stuck when I tried to call the move. The code is here (it's not very clean and most of the properties present aren't even in use yet)

```
import math
import random
import time

class type (object):
        def __init__(self, name, relat):
                self.name = name
                self.relat = relat

#define types
fire = type("fire", None)
normal = type("normal", None)
water = type("water", None)
grass = type("grass", None)

#add relationships
fire.relat = {fire: 0.5, normal: 1, water: 0.5, grass: 2}
normal.relat = {fire: 1, normal: 1, water: 1, grass: 1}
water.relat = {fire: 2, normal: 1, water: 0.5, grass: 0.5}
grass.relat = {fire: 0.5, normal: 1, water: 2, grass: 0.5}

#call the variable of fire relationship with water
print fire.relat[water]

class move (object):
        def __init__(self, name, damage, type, ps):
                self.name = name
                self.damage = damage
                self.type = type
                self.ps = ps

tackle = move("Tackle", 5, normal, "physical")
searingburst = move("Searing Burst", 5, fire, "special")
pinesmack = move("Pine Smack", 5, grass, "special")
refresher = move("Refresher", 5, water, "special")

class Pokemon(object):
        # Creates a Pokemon!
        def __init__(self, speciesname, nickname, gender, type1, type2, chp, thp, exp, acc, moves):
                self.speciesname = speciesname
                self.nickname = nickname
                self.gender = gender
                self.type1 = type1
                self.type2 = type2
                self.chp = chp
                self.thp = thp
                self.exp = exp
                self.damage = 2
                self.bacc = 0
                self.acc = acc
                self.moves = moves
        def displayhp(self):
                print str(self.chp) + "/" + str(self.thp) + " HP"
        def damageenemy(self, opponent):
                if ((opponent.type1).upper() == 'GHOST'):
                        opponent.chp = opponent.chp
                        print("%s's attack passed through %s!" % (self.nickname, opponent.nickname))
                        opponent.displayhp()
                else:
                        opponent.chp = opponent.chp - self.damage
                        opponent.displayhp()
        #make a Pokemon by defining a variable = Pokemon(speciesname, nickname etc...)

treecko = Pokemon("Treecko", "Treecko", "male", grass, None, 20, 20, 0, 0, [tackle, pinesmack])
krabby = Pokemon("Krabby", "Krabby", "male", water, None, 20, 20, 0, 0, [tackle, refresher])

def choose(o1, o2):
        o1r = input("What will %s do? " % o1.speciesname)
        if o1r in o1.moves:
                print o1r.moves
        else:
                print "no"

choose(treecko, krabby)
```

The current code will access the move class; what I need is the name of the move. So instead of checking for the object tackle inside the moves list, I want to check if the string "Tackle" is in the move class, inside the Moves list inside the object.

Comment: Why not create a dictionary of move objects, with move name as the key and move object as the value?

Comment: `type` is a builtin, you should use something like `PokeType`, `MoveType`, or even just capitalize `T`.  Also you aren't accounting for moves like Dragon Rage that deal set damage, moves like horn drill that attack multiple times, status moves, moves with non-100% accuracy, and all your damages are extremely low

Comment: Or, if you'd prefer to iterate through them, have a look at [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) as in, `any(x in o1.moves if x.move_type == 'tackle')`

Comment: It seems like youd' be better off creating a matrix of effectiveness that you look into like `effectiveness[FIRE][WATER]`, if you define your types as an enum (or similar) you could get O(1) lookup.

Comment: H-how did I overlook type? That's been fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think some tricks when select object you want to operate on will be enough.

And please don't use type as a class name. It's the name of a built-in function.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import math
import random
import time

class myType (object):
        def __init__(self, name, relat):
                self.name = name
                self.relat = relat

#define myTypes
fire = myType("fire", None)
normal = myType("normal", None)
water = myType("water", None)
grass = myType("grass", None)

#add relationships
fire.relat = {fire: 0.5, normal: 1, water: 0.5, grass: 2}
normal.relat = {fire: 1, normal: 1, water: 1, grass: 1}
water.relat = {fire: 2, normal: 1, water: 0.5, grass: 0.5}
grass.relat = {fire: 0.5, normal: 1, water: 2, grass: 0.5}

#call the variable of fire relationship with water
print fire.relat[water]

class move (object):
        def __init__(self, name, damage, myType, ps):
                self.name = name
                self.damage = damage
                self.myType = myType
                self.ps = ps


tackle = move("Tackle", 5, normal, "physical")
searingburst = move("Searing Burst", 5, fire, "special")
pinesmack = move("Pine Smack", 5, grass, "special")
refresher = move("Refresher", 5, water, "special")

class Pokemon(object):
        # Creates a Pokemon!
        def __init__(self, speciesname, nickname, gender, myType1, myType2, chp, thp, exp, acc, moves):
                self.speciesname = speciesname
                self.nickname = nickname
                self.gender = gender
                self.myType1 = myType1
                self.myType2 = myType2
                self.chp = chp
                self.thp = thp
                self.exp = exp
                self.damage = 2
                self.bacc = 0
                self.acc = acc
                self.moves = moves
        def displayhp(self):
                print str(self.chp) + "/" + str(self.thp) + " HP"
        def damageenemy(self, opponent):
                if ((opponent.myType1).upper() == 'GHOST'):
                        opponent.chp = opponent.chp
                        print("%s's attack passed through %s!" % (self.nickname, opponent.nickname))
                        opponent.displayhp()
                else:
                        opponent.chp = opponent.chp - self.damage
                        opponent.displayhp()
        #make a Pokemon by defining a variable = Pokemon(speciesname, nickname etc...)

treecko = Pokemon("Treecko", "Treecko", "male", grass, None, 20, 20, 0, 0, [tackle, pinesmack])
krabby = Pokemon("Krabby", "Krabby", "male", water, None, 20, 20, 0, 0, [tackle, refresher])

def choose(o1, o2):
        o1r = input("What will %s do? enter 1 for tackle, 2 for pinesmack: " % o1.speciesname)
        print type(o1r)
        if 1 == o1r:
            print o1.moves[0]
        elif 2 == o1r:
            print o1.moves[1]
        else:
            assert 0, 'wrong input!'

#         if o1r in o1.moves:
#                 print o1r.moves
#         else:
#                 print "no"

choose(treecko, krabby)
```

Tell me if it works for you.

Comment: This actually does work, if just for one Pokemon. I'll try to structure moves to have {move, move.name} or something of the like, as it'll save time in the long run.

Comment: @VitaminBasketball  OK. If it helps you, please accept it as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
if o1r in (lambda move : move.name)(o1.moves):
    print o1r.moves
```

is what you want. This will pull out the name of the move

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Here is what I meant in the comment: 
In the pokemon class init function:

```
self.moves = {move.name:move for move in moves}
```

and then in your choose function:

```
if o1r in o1.moves:
    print 'Move {o} caused damage {1}'.format(o1r, o1.moves[o1r].damage)
```